# Menu item in ActionPane sometimes dissapears

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a strange issue where a menu item/button on the ActionPane in a listpage form sometimes dissapears, and randomly appears again.

The user has the rights to use this menu item, I have tried to delete all user data, removed the AUC files of the user. I have restarted AX2012 after each action taken.

The last time the menu item showed again when restarting AX2012, the other time it popped up when switching company's. This all isn't working anymore.

It is a custom menu item on the Released products list page, the menu item is a copy of "Edit" with a small modification (loading extra tabs, that are not loading when clicking the "Edit" button.

Other users don't have this problem, any idea why the menu items sometimes dissapears, and how to get it back?

Comment: Is this a custom form/menu item or standard? If standard, could you tell us which form and menu item?

Comment: It is a custom menu item on the Released products list page, the menu item is a copy of "Edit" with a small modification (loading extra tabs, that are not loading when clicking the "Edit" button.) The Edit button is not giving any problems.

Comment: If only for some users try to delete the user from **AX** and then recreate it.

Comment: When you say disappears, do you mean becomes disabled? Or actually disappears?

Comment: It actually dissapears, we have planned to recreate the user tomorrow, i will let you know if this solves the problem.

Comment: I have tried recreating the user, it doesn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I hope to understood the question, the issue it' probably caused by UsageData, if are you able to replicate the case, try to *Reset* the Form/Listpage :
[image: resetForm]

The missing MenuItem, User has it hidden.

Godd work.